# IOS: Unregister font registered with CoreText

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I'm loading ttf fonts at runtime and registering them using CoreText. Later, when the font is updated, I unregister the font from CoreText, download the latest version from a server and register the font with CoreText again.

This almost works, but it seems like the font is cached and not updated until my app is terminated and restarted.

What is the proper way to unregister a font and remove it from any caches?

I use this code to unregister the font:

```
NSURL *url = /* My url to the font */;
CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef) url);
CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
CFErrorRef error = nil;
CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &error);

CGFontRelease(newFont);

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error unregistering font: %@", error);
}

return newFontName;
```

One thing that I feel is wrong, but don't know how to fix, is how I get the `CGFontRef`. Does `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` create new references each time, or do I get a reference to an already registered `CGFontRef` if it exists? Is there a better way to get the `CGFontRef` for an already registered font?

I have only used the font to create dynamic `UIImage` instances, so I don't think there's any label or other UI element keeping a reference to the font.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: This still happens in iOS 12. Works in the simulator as expected though. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I assume it's a bug of iOS 7.
Have you tried to run this in iOS 6 ?